# What's the protocol string for accessories from Apple?

Tags: ios, external-accessory

My company has a project need to fetch some data from the product
and I started with EADemo

Which protocol string to use when I have the adapter
http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter?fnode=85&fs=f%3Dcable%26fh%3D459d%252B45c4

Thanks!

Comment: @T-Heron hi! i do some research and knowing that if i want to access an accessory i have to find out the "Supported external accessory protocols". but accessories from apple, I'm not sure if it need one, and my company won't buy one till I know what exactly the answer is. 
Thanks!

Comment: OK. i found the answer is that "Apple lightning to usb camera adapter" does not have a protocol string

Comment: Good job.  You should put this as an answer to your own question and mark it, rather than just leave it as a comment, in my opinion.